# Wearing course for Helipad

Tags: civil-engineering, aviation

I am tasked with the design of a helipad for a remote government facility. Annex 14 Part II (ICAO Convention on International Civil Aviation) does not clearly state what materials are acceptable.

The most common materials are concrete and asphalt.

I want to use brick pavers.

Does anyone know of any risks or restrictions in this regard?

Comment: Risk 1 : one gets dislodged and takes out rotor....

Comment: Risk 2: dust and small particles...

Comment: Depending on the purpose for the helipad & the pavers used, some pavers can produce a bumpy, or uneven surface which would affect wheeled devices such a wheelchairs trollies or hospital gurneys. Also, they could create small puddles during rail fall.

Comment: Grass is perfectly acceptable so far as the helicopter is concerned, but as @Fred says it might not be acceptable to the users on the ground.

Comment: @SolarMike since the downwash from a helicopter rotor is erm, *downwards* (and outwards from the helicopter) the chance of it causing something big and heavy on the ground to hit the rotor blades is remote. This is a very different airflow pattern from loose objects on the ground being sucked into jet engine intakes, which *is* a real-life problem.

Comment: @alephzero so no need to keep helipads clean then... oh btw don't some helicopters use jet engines... Given the news in UK recently reducing risk of engine failure is a priority IMHO

Comment: So all replies are opinions, but no particular design code, or requirements?